# Android: getting very blurred image from capture camera

Tags: android

I'm capturing image from camera in horizontal scroll-view .When i select that image and display in full image in Image-view its getting very blurry. Why not display clear image in imageview.How to solve this .Thanks in advance

```
 btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                                Log.e("Camera", " Open");
                            }
                        });



 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
 Bitmap photoBitMap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");}
}
```

Comment: This `data.getExtras().get("data")` will return you the thumbnail data and when you try to scale it on large imageview it will get blurred. There are many ways to get full bitmap.

Comment: But in sd card it also save the blur image.

Comment: This indicates problem with the camera itself. does this happen when using stock camera app ?

Comment: @p.ld, can you please check your camera settings, it may be low resolution.